# Adding new characters cause splitting line into many lines

Tags: indentation, line-breaks

I'm analyzing a lot of logs using VIM version 7.3 (2010 Aug 15, compiled Sep 24 2013 13:45:11). 
Recently I obtained logs that look like this:

```
     3521:2015-09-28T09:18:36.922557+00:00 192 [info]  »   ERR:  00 LINUX-0-<2015-09-28T09:18:36.922555Z> 22E ERR/APP/Error, (pid:558) name : SomeApplication#015¶
```

but after inserting any word at the end of a line it changes to 3 lines like so:

```
3521:2015-09-28T09:18:36.922557+00:00 192 [info]  »   ERR:  00¶
LINUX-0-<2015-09-28T09:18:36.922555Z> 22E ERR/APP/Error, (pid:558) name :¶
SomeApplication#015 %%%¶
```

My .vimrc:

```
set cindent¶
set nowrap¶
set hidden¶
set number¶
set ignorecase¶
set tabstop=6 shiftwidth=4 softtabstop=4 expandtab¶
set listchars=tab:»\ ,eol:¶,trail:·,   " show invisible characters as in eclipse IDE¶
nmap <CR> o<Esc>¶
nnoremap <silent> <Space> :silent noh<Bar>echo<CR>¶

" user defined commands¶
command DBGPrint ! cat % <Bar> grep \%\%\% <Bar> less¶
command! -nargs=1 Filter %y z <Bar> tabnew <Bar> 0put=@z <Bar> %!grep -in "<args>"¶
command! -nargs=1 FilterSens %y z <Bar> tabnew <Bar> 0put=@z <Bar> %!grep -n "<args>"¶
```

EDIT:
I added

```
set textwidth=0
set wrapmargin=0
```

at the end of my .vimrc file but when opening log file I have it set to *textwidth=78*.
When I execute *set textwidth=0* in open file - it works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `set textwidth=0` to not break up long lines. See `:h tw`. Note that if you set the textwidth to 0, then wrapmargin might take effect, see `:h wm`, so consider also using `set wrapmargin=0`.

Comment: Or actually it resolved my issue when typing "set textwidth=0" into vim. When I typed it into my .vimrc - the issue still happens. Any idea why?

Comment: I use Majutsushi TagBar, and NERDTree plugins.

Comment: Try putting it at the bottom of your .vimrc

Comment: To check the value at run time, just type `set tw`, so you can check if it's actually 0 or not.