# Vim keeps auto wrapping lines when in insert mode, how can we change this?

Tags: wrapping

I'm not sure why this started to happen but recently vim seems to have begun autowrapping lines when in insert mode. It's pretty annoying.

I use the following modules

```
'vim-ruby/vim-ruby'
'rodjek/vim-puppet'
'romainl/Apprentice'
'plasticboy/vim-markdown'
```

I also have the following set

```
set wildmode=longest,full
set textwidth=80
set autoindent
```

It pretty much happens in all files so filetype seems to not matter. The full vimrc can be seen here https://pastebin.com/1kpUmXFd

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding new characters cause splitting line into many lines](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/5018/adding-new-characters-cause-splitting-line-into-many-lines)

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se], Biff! You can usually work around that by setting `:set tw=0`. But usually Vim will wrap lines depending on the file type you're editing. Can you take a look and share what file type you're editing when this happens? Also post the result of `:set ft?` and `:set fo?`, since the former can confirm the file type and the latter is involved in the decisions on when to wrap long lines after the `'textwidth'` is reached...

Comment: Well the tw being set to 80 like I have has been set for decades now without issue. It's only recently upon entering insert mode or writing text that the wrapping happens. 

It's every ft.

The fo is formatoptions=croql

Comment: If you have `fo=croql`, then it means only *comments* will be broken at `'textwidth'`. Is it possible that what you're seeing is only happening on lines that have comments? If you remove the `c` from that option (`:set fo-=c`), then Vim should stop breaking lines at `tw` when those lines are comments...

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `tw=79` and `textwidth=80` from you .vimrc and Vim will not wrap lines.

Comment: This would be a stronger answer if it included an explanation: *why* do these steps solve the problem? In the comments, OP mentions they've had these settings for a while, and only recently has the problem emerged